# add pagination control for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, tdd, nunit

I am new to asp.net MVC. I am trying to understand how to add pagination for a list of items using MVC without code for a view. I am using nunit testing to check whether pager option is tested or not

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in pagination for a vanilla MVC project -- you'll need to write one yourself or find something off the shelf.

See [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList), which is also available on NuGet.